# Let $V$ be an n-dimensional vector space over a field $K$. Why does this definition make sense?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $V$ be an n-dimensional vector space over a field $K$, $A=\mbox{End}(V)=\{T:V\rightarrow V\ |\ \mbox{T is a linear application}\}$ and $B=M_{n \times n}(K)$

$\beta=(v_1,...,v_n)$ a base of $V$. For $T\in A$ we define $[T]_\beta\in M_{n\times n}(K)$ as $T(v_i)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n ([T]_\beta)_{ki}\cdot v_k$

I don't understand this definition

Comment: $A$ is the set of linear maps from a vector space to itself, which is a ring under addition and composition.

Comment: Notice that $[T]_\beta$ is just the matrix representing the map $T$ in the basis $\beta$.

Comment: Ok I get it: $T(v_i)$ is a linear combination of the basis vectors $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \alpha_{k,i} \cdot v_k$ so the $\alpha_{k,i}$ form a matirix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is defining the matrix $[T]_\beta$ by its coefficients, basically by columns.

Observe that, for fixed $i$, the vector $T(v_i)$ - as every vector - can be uniquely written as a linear combination of the basis elements $v_k$.

> Let the $k$th element of the $i$th column of $[T]_\beta$ be the coefficient of $v_k$ in this linear combination.

So that, we will indeed have $T(v_i)=\sum_k ([T]_\beta)_{k,i}\cdot v_k$.

Comment: Well, that's the case for $T=$ identity of $V$.

Comment: ... Yup.  More coffee needed.  Thanks!